# Factorising a multivariate polynomial, in terms of products of linear polynomials, using blowups

Tags: polynomials, convex-polytopes, factorization, blow-ups

I am considering multivariate polynomials of the form

$$f(x,y)=x^a\,y^b\,p(x,y)^c$$

(and similarly for higher dimensions). I am trying to transform these polynomials into the generic form

$$\widetilde{f}(x,y)=g_1(x)^{p_{1}}\cdots g_n(x)^{p_{n}}\,k_1(y)^{q_1}\cdots k_m(y)^{q_m}$$

via a series of coordinate transformations, with the resulting functions $g_i,k_i$ polynomials. These transformations can be anything as long as the Jacobian of the transformation is not zero.

For example, consider

$$f(x,y)=x\,y\,(s t+s (x+y)+x y)$$

with $s$, $t$ constants. By performing the transformation

$$
y\to\left(-\frac{s (t+x)}{s+x}\right)\,y \qquad x \to x
$$

I obtain

$$
\widetilde{f}(x,y)=s^2 x\,(s+x)^{-1}\,(t+x)^2\,y\,(y-1)
$$

which is of the desired form.

In general, whilst tackling this problem I have "discovered" that if $p(x,y)$ is linear in at least one of $x$ or $y$, (say $y$ w.l.o.g.) then the transformation

$$
y\to f(x)\,y
$$

where $f(x)$ is the solution to $p(x,y)=0$ for $y$, will bring the polynomial to the desired form. This is the general case of the example illustrated above. Interestingly, to me this seems as a sort of "generalisation" of blowups, where normally one blows up a polynomial at one point, but this transformation does the trick "globally".

However, if $p(x,y)$ is quadratic in $x,y$ or worse, then the method illustrated above does not work, and I always obtain some "mixed" factors, or worse, square roots with mixed factors.

My question is, is there a known solution to this problem? Can any multivariate polynomial even be cast in such a form? If so, does anyone know of, or could point me to a solution/further reading with regards to this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I have a friend who invented a mapping from polynomials of real variables to a noncommutative matrix form and succeeds in factoring.  It worked very well on test cases.  I can link you to an article, or even send this problem to him.   His name is Konrad Schemmpf and has several papers in Arxiv.   The algorithm was implemented in the Fricas code; I think it's a package by now.

Comment: I would be very interested in such articles, or even getting in contact with your friend! Thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: I contacted him, we will see.  Here are some publications from arxiv   --
https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.09102
and google search term  
--
konrad schrempf arxiv